# Failed to find mesh file, File or path does not exist

Tags: gazebo, urdf

I am trying to run a URDF robot in gazebo and continue to get errors of trying to find meshes. I have tried using a relative file path and a hard coded file path. It also says URI not supported by Fuel but I am not trying to use Ignition or fuel, only gazebo.

Here is the Error code:

```
[gazebo-1] [Wrn] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:313] URI not supported by Fuel [model://$HOME/ros2_ws/src/sim/description/urdf/ur_description/meshes/ur10/collision/Wrist1.dae]
[gazebo-1] [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://$HOME/ros2_ws/src/sim/description/urdf/ur_description/meshes/ur10/collision/Wrist1.dae]
[gazebo-1] [Err] [MeshShape.cc:64] Failed to find mesh file [model://$HOME/ros2_ws/src/sim/description/urdf/ur_description/meshes/ur10/collision/Wrist1.dae]
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Fischdog24. Have you tried spelling out the path instead of using $HOME?

Comment: @Chuck Thank you! I have tried using that as well and it comes back with the same error

Comment: I want to use a relative path in the end though and was just trying to use an absolute path to get a start, the start of the URDF uses package:// to try and find that relative path

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the URDF that's throwing this error? What is the path where the URDF is located?

Comment: @Chuck yes I am able to edit the URDF, the path of the URDF is located in my package that is in my install file of my Colcon build, but my meshes are located in my package that is in the src folder

Comment: I did get it working with an absolute path using /home but still not working with using a relative path

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [gazebo-classic tutorial pages](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_robot) on how to create a model. You want to look at "Model structure and requirements", "Make a Model" and "Attach meshes".

gazebo expects you to set the environment variable GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH to one or more directories which it will search for model definitions.

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-11/models:$HOME/.gazebo/models
```

In the sdf file, you can then refer to a model using just its name. In these examples the model names are `ground_plane` and `pioneer2dx`:

```
<include><uri>model://ground_plane</uri></include>

<mesh><uri>model://pioneer2dx/meshes/chassis.dae</uri></mesh>
```